# Where does "Santa" in Santa Claus come from?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-gender, christmas

Santa Claus is a man, right? In this case, he may not be fine with the fact that people call him *Santa*, which is the [Spanish](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=santa) and [Portuguese](http://www.wordreference.com/pten/santa) word for **female** saint names.  For example, Santa Barbara and Santa Monica (Barbara and Monica are both female names). Saint Nicholas is by the way translated as *San Nicolas* and *São Nicolas*, respectively, in these languages, as *San* and *São* are the words for male saint names.

Where does *Santa* in Santa Claus come from?

Comment: I think that it might also be pointed out, for completeness, that "Klaas" as well as its cognate in German "Claus" are variants of the name "Nicholas" in those languages: Niklaas and Niklaus, respectively.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The name "Santa Claus" comes from a dialect of Dutch, [where the word was "Sante Klaas"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Santa+Claus).

In this case, it was not a feminine suffix; the word evolved into *Santa*, which only coincidentally looks like the feminine form of *saint* in some languages.

(The Dutch word does come from the same origins as the Spanish and Portuguese, incidentally; most Germanic languages borrowed this Romance word and made it their own.)

Answer (score 2):

**Sanctus Nicolaus**:

> The modern figure of Santa Claus is derived from the Dutch figure of
>   ***[Sinterklaas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas)***, whose name is a dialectal pronunciation of *[Saint Nicholas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Nicholas)*, the historical Greek bishop.